# moment-countdown js library giving me a weird variable assignment?

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs, countdownjs.js

The library I am using: https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown -->
  <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="moment-countdown.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="timeInputHTML" onchange="mainfunc()>
  <p id="pel"></p>
  <script>
    function mainfunc() {
      timeVar = document.getElementById("timeInputHTML").value;
      // var timeInputVar = moment("2045-01-01 00:00:00").countdown().toString(); 
      var timeInputVar = moment(timeVar).countdown().toString();
      document.getElementById("pel").innerHTML = timeInputVar;
    }

    // Run above function every 1 second
    setInterval(mainfunc, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The question: How do I make the variable `timeVar` when it obtains its values from `timeInputHTML` in the HTML code, not contain contain a T in the middle like so: `"2018-05-05T14:30"` I believe this is what is wrong with my code and is causing the `Uncaught TypeError` if it is not the issue then please can you explain to me what is please?

The image / screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Note that your `onchange="mainfunc()>` is missing a closing `"`. (better not to attach handlers in HTML at all, though - attach Javascript handlerse with Javascript instead)

Comment: Many thanks, that fixed it! Always the simple things was overthinking it.I will leave the question here, as to indicate to others that the T value works inside that var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown -->
  <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="moment-countdown.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="timeInputHTML" onchange="mainfunc()">
  <p id="pel"></p>
  <script>
    function mainfunc() {
      timeVar = document.getElementById("timeInputHTML").value;
      // var timeInputVar = moment("2045-01-01 00:00:00").countdown().toString(); 
      var timeInputVar = moment(timeVar).countdown().toString();
      document.getElementById("pel").innerHTML = timeInputVar;
    }

    // Run above function every 1 second
    setInterval(mainfunc, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

your are missing **"** this in input function it should be like this

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="timeInputHTML" onchange="mainfunc()">
```